# asp.net mvc: Index was out of range exception in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, exception

In jQuery I need to have something like this:

```
if (@(Model.ListItems.Count) > 0)
          if ('@(Model.ListItems[0].Date)' != '')
               .......
```

which when Model.ListItems.Count is 0 won't work, as it throws

> Index was out of range

Exception in the next line. It makes sense to act like this, because of the evaluation of expressions, but what can I do to act as I intend?

Comment: You have a debugger. Set the appropriate break points and see what state your model is in when it hits that line.

Comment: what is the jquery code you are trying to run?

Comment: it breaks in the second line I wrote and in fact it should break, because razor expression is evaluated first. my question was what to do prevent that

Comment: try taking the brackets off @(Model.ListItems.Count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured this out:
the code becomes:

```
@if (Model.ListItems.Count > 0) 
{
    if (Model.ListItems[0].Date!= null)
        <text>
             ......
         </text>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing up your client script and javascript.

Why exactly would you think that a javascript `if` branch would affect the server side code razor code as it replaces your `@(...)` expressions in the html response?

You need to do the branching logic in razor itself so that it executes server side.